# Wordpress wp-admin/setup-config.php homepage redirect loop

Tags: wordpress

I have a common problem that many of us already encountered before.

I installed Wordpress on a subdomain on my server. The Homepage (www.mydomain.com) keeps redirecting to www.mydomain.com/wp-admin/setup-config.php.

Interestingly, other pages than the home page (f.i. www.mydomain.com/blog) DOES NOT redirect. Those work fine. It is just the homepage (www.mydomain.com/) itself that redirects.

I use the Illdy theme as a child theme.

I did already:

- Checked/repaired the tables in MySQL
- Checked siteurl and home in the wp-options table
- Checked the table-prefix in wp-config
- checked the wp-config that everything is alright
- Deleted/tried different .htcacces files
- Set up static front page (tried also latest post as alternative, no change)

Intersting is also that in the customnizer of the Illdy theme, I can see the homepage itself in the preview. No redirect here.

Sadly I also did fix this issue once before, also on a subdomain but with a child theme of Sydney. But unfortuantely I forgot completely what I did back then and don't get it together anymore :(

Any ideas what it could be?

Comment: Did you try updating the permalinks through the Wordpress backend? Also, delete the sample wp-config if it exists.

Comment: Hello,

thank you for your comment.

Yes, I tried also to update the permalinks trough the backend.

Also tried to delete the wp-config-sample.php as you suggested.

Unfortunately no change.

Answer (score 6):

OK, got it.

It was the Browser Cache. I just refreshed the page with the shift-F5 all the time, but nope, needed to empty the cache.

Don't really understand why actually, but anyway, problem solved and lesson learned. :)

Comment: I installed about 30 WordPress sites and this is not happening to me till now :-)
Thank you for help! Browser Cache was the last place that I would look for

Comment: Worked for me, I think it mostly depends on the hosting's cache settings.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a permission problem. I solved with this commands.

```
chown www-data:www-data  -R * # Let Apache be owner
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;  # Change directory permissions rwxr-xr-x
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;  # Change file permissions rw-r--r--
```